# How to upload files unzipped by zip.js with Plupload

Tags: javascript, zip, plupload

I want to unzip a zip file by [zip.js](https://github.com/gildas-lormeau/zip.js) in the front-end, and then upload some of the unzipped files with [Plupload](https://www.plupload.com/).

I'm new with Plupload. I know Plupload read files selected by user, but I can't figure out how to get Plupload read Files unzipped by zip.js. How can I make it?

Answer (score 1):

Manually adding files is only possible in the `HTML5` runtime. All other runtimes do not support it (*for obvious reasons*). If that's ok in your case, there is this method [addFile](https://www.plupload.com/docs/v2/Uploader#addFile-method-filefileName). It can accept Blob (*or File*) as the first argument and `fileName` as the optional second one.

So if `zip.js` produces Blob on any stage of the extraction operation, you can simply pipe that Blob into your Plupload instance and it will be added to the upload queue, just as if it was picked or dropped into it from the desktop.